# Fineuploader IE9 CORS iframe error "object doesn't support property or method '_parseJsonResponse'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cors, fine-uploader, cross-domain-policy

Using Fineuploader 5.0.3 against a java server stack that is closely based on your sample.

All uploads work fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE 10 and greater.  This only seems to happen in IE 9 or lower.  I have tested on multiple machines in different environments with the same result.

Here are debug logs from the session on IE9:

```
[Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Received 1 files or inputs.
[Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Sending simple upload request for 0
[Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Sending upload request for 0
[Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Received iframe load event for CORS upload request (iframe name 0_3da0a2e3-33f1-46a0-a172-cec58610a2a1)
[Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Received the following window message: '{"success": true, "uuid":"23763c4a-e282-4c03-9d7d-c863d307755d", "auth":"12345", "objectid":"1076"}'
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method '_parseJsonResponse'
File: fineuploader.js, Line: 4799, Column: 17
[Fine Uploader 5.0.3] No valid message received from loaded iframe for iframe name 0_3da0a2e3-33f1-46a0-a172-cec58610a2a1
[Fine Uploader 5.0.3] iframe loaded
[Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Simple upload request failed for 0
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a regression in 5.0.0.  I have filed [a bug in the project's issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1272) and scheduled the fix for v5.0.5.

A quick workaround would be to change this line:

```
response = handler._parseJsonResponse(fileId, message),
```

to this:

```
response = qq.parseJson(message);
```

In the source.  However, a better long term fix (which we should incorporate into an upcoming hotfix release) involves reversing [the commit where we moved around the function that delegates to `qq.parseJson` for form-based uploads](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/commit/81d5125420eb6ff7b2f3f8bdcabe83b9f3572225).

Comment: Thanks this workaround works perfectly with one small modification.  There should be a comma at the end of the updated line, not a semicolon.

Comment: Yep, sounds right.  I didn't test before posting.  This will be fixed in 5.0.5.